# php artisan up command not working in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this very strange problem in laravel. I successfully put my website into maintenance mode via artisan by this command:

```
php artisan down
```

But now i have to put my website back into live mode.I tried:

```
php artisan up
```

However, the site isn't going live even though i get success message? Have you guys ever faced this issue?
Whats the fix?

I'm on :

```
1. Macbook pro Mamp
2. Laravel 5.1
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there an error message which you get when you try to start it up again?

Comment: no.. there was no issue at all.. it just didn't work.. however i have got the answer below. Thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**artisan up** command simply deletes **storage/framework/down** file. Please check if the file exits after you execute the **up** command. If it still exists, it seems like a file access issue. Whenever you run **down/up** commands, make sure that you run them as the same user that is running your application.

In order to get the site up and running again, remove the **storage/framework/down** file manually.

Comment: Awesome..!!! It worked.. however its strange that UP command is not working.. If it was file access issue then it should have created down file too right?

Comment: I can only guess. One scenario could be running down command as "root" and up command as some other user - removing the file could not work, but you wouldn't get any error because of silencing operator @ being used in the up command.